# Datatables works fine with my data, until I try adding the header and footer for the columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following HTML :

```
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
    <!--<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>-->
</table>
```

and I am trying to bind as follows :

```
    var resultA = JSON.parse(result);


    $('#datatables').DataTable( {
        "data":resultA,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "description" }
        ]
    });
```

The header and footer are commented out for now and when I do this, my data appears in the table. But when I uncomment the header and footer, I get no data, just the header and footer! What am I doing wrong?

Also, I know datatables supports ajax calls, due to the way the API I am calling authenticates, it MUST be a separate call, and populated in the way I have it here, without the built in ajax.

I know I am doing something absolutely STUPID, but what could it be?

UPDATE : ACTIONS I NEED TO ADD TO ACTIONS COLUMN :

```
<td class="text-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon like"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the options fixedHeader.header and fixedHeader.footer:

```
fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
    }
```

try this:

```
$('#datatables').DataTable( {
    "data":resultA,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "description" },
        {
           "data":null
           "defaultContent":"<a href='#' class='btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon like'><i class='material-icons'>favorite</i></a>
<a href='#' class='btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit'><i class='material-icons'>dvr</i></a>
<a href='#' class='btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove'><i class='material-icons'>close</i></a>"
        }
    ],
    fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
    }
});
```

More details [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html).

Comment: When I do this, the data appears still, but I still don't have a header or footer?

Comment: In your columns you only specify 2 columns. In the HTML I see 3. What about the actions column?

Comment: Oh my god. I am a moron! Thanks!!

Comment: I already marked your answer as "correct" but I have another question about this is you have a moment? I have updated the question above to show the actions I want... If I wanted to add that to every actions row, how would I do it?

Comment: For that you use the defaultContent option. This probably should be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks!! I will ask a separate question anyway, because I still need to work out how to differentiate them.

Comment: Haha, damn - I have to wait 90 minutes to post another question! I will ask tomorrow.